# Use Disqus With Star Rating

Tags: javascript, disqus

I know out of the box disqus does not have any rating features. Is there anything currently out there that would allow to integrate some sort of star rating plugin with disqus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google search showed a number of interesting options.

You should check out the JQuery star rating plugin.

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

Another option is `jtinder`

https://github.com/do-web/jTinder

> jTinder is a javascript library that makes rating people, products,
>   images very easy and fast. It is optimized for mobile touch device but
>   has also a desktop fallback.

There's also the `rateit` plugin

https://rateit.codeplex.com/

If you are using `react-js` you can use the `react-star-rating-input` plugin

https://github.com/ikr/react-star-rating-input

> React.js component for entering 0-5 (or more) stars

Then there's `raty`

https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I shall see if any can work with disqus.